# Get time from text

Tags: javascript, regex, time

I am trying to extract just the time from a string using regex. So for example time could be in the 12 hour format `9pm , 9am` or in 24 hour format `20:00`. I have written the following expression however it only seems to work for 12 hour format.

```
var re = /(([0-1]{0,1}[0-9])|(2[0-3]))(:|.)[0-5]{0,1}[0-9][ ]?(AM|am|PM|pm)?/g;

var stringToCheck = "Foo Fighters are playing on the main stage at 20:00."; 

var arr = re.exec(stringToCheck);
console.log(arr);
```

Running this code prints out null. Is it the regex?

Comment: You might want to give more examples of what exactly are you trying to match ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will seem a little long but does the job nicely.

**Regex:** `(?:[0][0-9]|[1][012])(?::[0-5][0-9])?(?:[AP]M|[ap]m)|(?:[0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5][0-9])`

**Explanation:**

- `(?:[0][0-9]|[1][012])` matches the hour part for `12 hour` format.
- `(?::[0-5][0-9])` matches the optional minute part (if you ever include) for `12 hour` format.
- `(?:[AP]M|[ap]m)` matches meridian suffix or you can simply write `(?:[ap]m)` and make it case insensitive using flag `i`.
- `(?:[0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5][0-9])` matches the `24 hour` format.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gO4kO1/7)**

Comment: A bit shorter: [`(?:0\d|1[0-2])(?::[0-5]\d)?(?:[AP]M|[ap]m)|(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/gO4kO1/8)

Comment: @Thomas: Nice. Though this solution is accepted by OP am looking for more info on this question as you might note that for 12 hour format there has to be two digits in hours while in question OP mentioned only one digit.

Comment: @Thomas: Exactly. Thanks. You can edit the answer if you like. But with appropriate explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e4w45wen/) your regex, and the rest, works. At least for your example string. Haven't tested it against other strings.

Code:

```
var re = /(([0-1]{0,1}[0-9])|(2[0-3]))(:|.)[0-5]{0,1}[0-9][ ]?(AM|am|PM|pm)?/g;
var stringToCheck = "Foo Fighters are playing on the main stage at 20:00."; 
var arr = re.exec(stringToCheck);
document.write(arr);
```

You do have some capture groups in the regex though that I don't know if you really want.

Regards